# Can't figure out formatting error while posting this question

Tags: support, specific-question, formatting

I get the error below while posting a question on Stack Overflow. I've looked up elsewhere, used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, and added extra lines after the heading, but I am  still getting this error.

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

You can view my raw code here

https://pastebin.com/vtacT4gP

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: Have you tried to apply the things a little at a time? I've pasted this in an Answer, and it doesn't seem to complain. On a side note, I think that using three `*` is one too many.

Comment: (The [articles are missing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) from your Stack Overflow question - both [definite articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Definite_article) and [indefinite articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Indefinite_article).)

Comment: @Scratte did you try pasting this in an answer on stackoverflow.com ? Because it was giving the bad code format error

Comment: I tried to paste it into an Answer on this post. But I never clicked on "Post Your Answer"

Comment: @Scratte `***` is "strong emphasis": `*emphasis*` – *emphasis*, `**strong**` – **strong**, `***strong emphasis***` – ***strong emphasis***. (Unless you didn't mean this syntactically.)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out adding url in table was triggering bad code format so I changed

**From this**

```
| url | clicks | visits|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| http://mypage.com/example | 2 | 3|
| http://mypage.com/otherpage | 1 | 1|
```

**To this**

```
| url | clicks | visits |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| mypageurl/example | 2 | 3 |
| mypageurl/otherpage | 1 | 1 |
```

Since i just wanted to display an example of query result in a table.